# “a cien por cien”, “a cien por ciento” & “a ciento por ciento”

Tags: significado-en-contexto

quisiera confirmar si “a cien por cien”, “a cien por ciento” & “a ciento por ciento” son intercambiables. Por ejemplo, “ellos quieren dedicarse a sus trabajos a cien por cien/a cien por ciento/a ciento por ciento”. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cualquiera de las tres formas:

- cien por cien
- cien por ciento
- ciento por ciento

es correcta de acuerdo con [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/la-esquina-del-idioma-es-cien-por-cien-o-cien-por-ciento/) para referirse a la totalidad:

> Cuando el contexto no se refiere a una proporción, sino que indica totalidad se pueden emplear de manera indistinta las formas «ciento por ciento», «cien por ciento» y «cien por cien», p. ej.: «Adquirió el ciento por ciento de las acciones…»; «Aumentó al «cien por ciento» la entrega de becas estudiantiles…»; «Se cubrió el cien por cien de las plazas administrativas».

En cuanto al ejemplo en cuestión, es necesaria la contracción "al" puesto que las formas  mencionadas llevan artículo cuando van precedidas de preposición. De lo contrario, puede obviarse el artículo:

- Ellos quieren dedicarse a sus trabajos a**l** cien por cien/a**l** cien por ciento/a**l** ciento por ciento.
- Ellos quieren dedicarse cien por cien/cien por ciento/ciento por ciento a sus trabajos.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!